# "Your Communities" dropdown still shows my old rep counts for some sites

Tags: bug, reputation, top-bar

When I look at my network profile, I can see that my rep counts have already been recalculated after the question upvote value was increased. I now have about 350-450 extra rep on the five sites I most frequent (plus Skeptics, which is kind of an outlier for me).

[image]

But when I open the hamburger menu in the top-right, the "Your Communities" list still shows the old rep count for SciFi. Bizarrely, it shows the new rep counts for the other sites, and if I actually go on SciFi, it shows my new rep count in the top bar:

[image]

When I first started typing this question, "Your Communities" was showing the wrong value for Puzzling as well, but by the time I took the second screenshot it had fixed itself. I'm sure the value for SciFi will correct itself shortly as well, but what I want to know is, **why was it wrong in the first place?** Are the totals not updated in real-time? And if not, how come some were correct and others weren't?

It wasn't my browser cache, because I cleared that repeatedly and it was still happening.

Comment: *"It wasn't caching, btw, because I cleared my cache"* ... The servers cache a lot of stuff as well and _you_ can't clear their cache.

Comment: @Tom True. I'm not sure what gets cached on the server and what gets cached in your browser. Maybe that's the answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our rep recalculation has completed but our aggregator is still working through a big queue of items. The aggregator is what mirrors things to the network store and that's what the top bar is based on. I hope that answers your question. [I answered a similar one here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338182/497549). Thanks for your patience!