# The first upvote on my answer is not recorded in achievements

Tags: bug, achievements-dialog

[Prove constant exists such that a function is uniformly continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3434443/187867)

For my answer to this question, I got an upvote after a few minutes. However I didn't see it until I checked because it didn't show up in the achievements. I did get reputation for it.

The second upvote is recorded as one upvote on the achievements, +10.

Comment: Achievements are overall super wonky right now. I've had some upvotes not get shown, and a random notification "+10" that doesn't show up in the list I can't attribute to any post. I think the system is just backlogged like crazy. I imagine there's probably a lot going on behind the scenes right now.

Comment: @Carc It seems the upvote on this answer doesn't show either. And I guess meta got the upvote value change because I have double the reputation.

Comment: Ya, the reputations seem to all have been adjusted by now (or at least all my network accounts seem to have been updated already). I'd just wait it out and see if it resolves itself.

Comment: None of my upvotes are hitting my achievements

Comment: @Carcigenicate I've noticed the same issues as well. I agree it's most likely due to the extra work on the servers doing all of those recalculations with the question up vote reputation change to +10. Once that's done, I trust soon if not already, then things should get back to normal then.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Our rep recalculation has completed but our aggregator is still working through a big queue of items. The aggregator is what mirrors things to the network store and that's what the top bar is based on. Thanks for your patience!