# Weird increase in my reputation

Tags: support, reputation

I am a pretty new contributor so forgive me if this is some common phenomenon. I was writing an answer a few minutes ago on MathSE, but when I opened my profile to check on my reputation, there was a weird increase in my reputation (from 481 to 531) with no indication in my reputation summary (no new upvotes or downvotes). Also, when I checked on my account section from other sites, I found that my reputation was still 481. Is this a bug or something else?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please refer the blog post: [We’re Rewarding the Question Askers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reputation scores are currently in flux because reputation gains for past question upvotes have been increased from +5 to +10. See [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/) and [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338131/will-i-know-how-much-reputation-i-gained-from-the-change-in-question-rep) which explains a little about how it's being rolled out.

It's being calculated site-by-site and so rep will be in flux for a day or so while the servers work out - [a little more on that here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338182/the-first-upvote-on-my-answer-is-not-recorded-in-achievements).