# History of badges, reputation along with questions and answers

Tags: discussion

Is there a way we can go back to look at reputation/badges history?

i.e the number of questions(asked/answered) before getting a badge, and number of questions asked/answered after getting a badge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see your rep changes over time on your profile activity page, and it looks like actually, your rep **increased by nearly 400 from 139**.

Probably part of the confusion is due to the recent change making question upvotes worth 10 not 5. Many users have been [confused by this change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338184/178621).

[image]

Also, I'm able to see the votes and can confirm that question was only downvoted once. I wouldn't worry about *single* "driveby" downvotes without comments, they usually don't mean anything and only cost 2 points; often a little while later you'll get a random upvote from someone who disagrees with the downvote and that's a net +8.

If you get many downvotes, or downvotes with comments explaining what you should have done better, *that's* when to stop and think about whether the way you're asking questions isn't doing enough to help the people you're asking for free help.

[image]

Comment: @forkdbloke I would recommend against purposely trying to get reputation. Try to use Stackoverflow as a tool and ignore the gamification of it. Otherwise you may find the reverse effect.

Comment: Please do not interpret my effort as "purposely trying to get points" , Please show me , where have i tried to get points on porpose (without helping others?)