# Rep in hamburger is not updated for a single site

Tags: bug, reputation, reputation-recalc

We know reputation is recalculated for questions. My reputation also increased in all the sites and updated in the hamburger where you put list of the sites.

[image: List of sites with reputation]

My reputation on Science Fiction & Fantasy is also recalculated to 1547.

[image: My reputation on Science Fiction & Fantasy site]

This change. still showing the old reputation. This is only the issue with a single site.

Should I blame the cache?

Comment: The hamsters are working as hard as possible....

Comment: See my answer here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338199/135201 - the process that updates these is a little backed up at the moment but it'll happen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reputation not appearing in Rep. Notification Queue - yet it is given silently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313701/reputation-not-appearing-in-rep-notification-queue-yet-it-is-given-silently) reported in [this **comment**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313701/reputation-not-appearing-in-rep-notification-queue-yet-it-is-given-silently#comment1125943_313732). Reported 3 hours ago here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338182/282094